# how can I consume dynamic keys in json using java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and consuming an external rest service which gives json output in below format

```
{
parentKey: {
    uuid1: {
        key1: value,
        key2: value
        key3: {
            key1: value,
            key2: value
        }
    },
    uuid2: {
        key1: value,
        key2: value
        key3: {
            key1: value,
            key2: value
        }
    },
    uuid3: {
        key1: value,
        key2: value
        key3: {
            key1: value,
            key2: value
        }
    },
    }
```

}

Is there any way thru which I can consume uuid keys and transform them into pojo ?
I also want to save this uuid in pojo.

Comment: Use a `Map<String, YourKeyObject>` and do some optional transformations on that map afterwards.

Comment: was able to achieve this adding  Map<String, YourKeyObject> map in parent object. Thanks @luk2302